# retrieving value from CGI form textbox out of MySQL table

Tags: forms, perl, cgi

I have this form that looks like so in a cgi file:

```
print "<FORM NAME='LAYOUTFORM' ACTION='Handler.cgi' METHOD=POST>";
print "<table border='0' align=center>\n";
print "<tr><td>Search by:<SELECT ID='Forms Combo Box1' NAME='what_to_do'><OPTION VALUE='title'>Title</OPTION><OPTION VALUE='description'>Description</OPTION><OPTION   VALUE='author'>Author</OPTION></td>";
print "<td><INPUT ID='SearchArea' TYPE=TEXT NAME='searchbox' VALUE='' SIZE=27 MAXLENGTH=100></td>";
print "<td><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT NAME='searchbutton' VALUE='Search' ID='Form_Search'></td></tr>";
print "</table>\n";
print "</form>";
```

Then I have this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;
use CGI qw(:standard);

$searchinput = param('searchbox');

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

my $dbh = DBI->connect( "DBI:mysql:database", "username", "password" ) or
die( "Could not make connection to database: $DBI::errstr" );

my $sth = $dbh->prepare( q(SELECT * FROM BookStore WHERE bAuthor = $searchinput) ) or 
die( "Cannot prepare statement: ", $dbh->errstr(), "\n" );

my $rc = $sth->execute() or
die( "Cannot execute statement: ", $sth->errstr(), "\n" );
```

I am getting this error in commandline:

```
Uknown column '$searchinput' in 'where clause' at Search.cgi line 17.
```

What I am trying to do is the user would enter a name into the textbox on the main.cgi.  Then hit the search button and the search.cgi would retrieve the info of the row that matches in the column of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( q(SELECT * FROM BookStore WHERE bAuthor = $searchinput) ) or 
die( "Cannot prepare statement: ", $dbh->errstr(), "\n" );
```

To:

```
my $query = sprintf ('SELECT * FROM BookStore WHERE bAuthor = %s', 
                     $dbh->quote("$searchinput"));
```

Comment: That worked wonders and perfectly. Thank you very much will mark as answered.

Comment: Your first suggestion is [a disaster waiting to happen](http://xkcd.com/327/). Always use placeholders for untrusted user input.